# Laravel PNG image shows but GIF image doesn't?

Tags: laravel

I have the following files in the `public` folder:

```
public/test.png
public/test.gif
```

In `config/filesystems`

```
'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

The PNG file shows, the GIF doesn't (I get a 404). I ran `php artisan storage:link` and everything else is working fine, just the GIF files are not showing.

Comment: Are these image located in your `public/` folder or in `storage/app/public/`?

Comment: In the `public/` folder. Just tested putting them in `storage/app/public` and get the same behaviour.

Comment: Just found out that other GIF files do work, so it has to do with the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the path is correct. Names should be case sensitive (`image.gif` is not the same with `image.Gif`)

Comment: I'll mark this as the correct answer as the problem was in the filename... Thanks!